# Create new list from old using re.sub() in python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, xml

My goal is to take an XML file, pull out all instances of a specific element, remove the XML tags, then work on the remaining text.

I started with this, which works to remove the XML tags, but only from the entire XML file:

```
from urllib import urlopen
import re

url = [URL of XML FILE HERE]  #the url of the file to search

raw = urlopen(url).read()   #open the file and read it into variable

exp = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
text_only = exp.sub('',raw).strip()
```

I've also got this,  `text2 = soup.find_all('quoted-block')`, which creates a list of all the `quoted-block` elements (yes, I know I need to import BeautifulSoup).

But I can't figure out how to apply the regex to the list resulting from the soup.find_all.  I've tried to use `text_only = [item for item in text2 if exp.sub('',item).strip()]` and variations but I keep getting this error:  `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *take an XML file, pull out all instances of a specific element, remove the XML tags, then work on the remaining text.*  Why not use a proper XML parser which natively supports some DOM techniques like `getElementsByTagName($tag)` or XPath query? Then you can just parse the nodes' `.text` property.  Regex may not be the best tool for this job.

Comment: regex is definitely not the right tool for this job. look into e.g. the `lxml` library -- it can do everything you need to do with xml (and is a lot faster than BeautifulSoup).

Comment: I've not used BeautifulSoup before but what about `text_only = [soup.get_text(item) for item in soup.find_all('quoted_block')]`?  see dox on [`get_text`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to regex this. Instead just use [BeautifulSoup's existing support for grabbing text](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
quoted_blocks = soup.find_all('quoted-block')
text_chunks = [block.get_text() for block in quoted_blocks]
```